# how to get key's value in value in key-value pair dict

Tags: python

It is a weird question but I wondering if it is possible to build a dict that value contains key in key-value pairs in python. As following, I would like to rewrite the following class *SwitchTest* by replace duplicated *customer*, *product*, *animal* in value from key-value pair of instance. How can I do that? or more specifically how can I get key's value in value inside a dictionary?

```
class Product():
    def __init__(self, para):
        self.para = para
        .....

class Animal():
    def __init__(self, para):
        self.para = para
        ....

class Human():
    def __init__(self, para):
        self.para = para
        ....


class SwitchTest():
    def __init__(self):
        instance = {'customer': lambda x: setattr(SwitchTest, 'customer', Human(x)),
                      'product': lambda x: setattr(self, 'product', Product(x)),
                      'animal': lambda x: setattr(self, 'animal', Animal(x))}
```

Comment: Is that the input or the expected output?  Show both please.

Comment: How are you determining the third element of the values?

Comment: Do you have something like `for user, number in <whatever>:`, and you want to know how to add a new value to the dict out of that? If so, you can do something like `users[user] = (f'user_{user}', f'address_{user}', number)`. Or any other string-formatting mechanism you prefer. The exact same way you put string values into strings for printing.

Answer (score 0):

Any meaning behind the numbers?

```
initial_dict = {'a': 987, 'b': 18, 'c': 9, 'd': 87}
users = {k: ('user_{}'.format(k),'address_{}'.format(k), v) for k, v in initial_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': ('user_a', 'address_a', 987),
 'b': ('user_b', 'address_b', 18),
 'c': ('user_c', 'address_c', 9),
 'd': ('user_d', 'address_d', 87)}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't quite understand why you would like to store the key also in the value. This goes against the concept of a dictionary.*

What if instead you would just **add the key to the value upon returning it**, so that you'd have some custom dict:

```
users = c_dict(
a = ('user', 'address', 987),
# ...
)
```

that **upon getting the value adds the key to the return**:

```
In [32]: users['a']
Out[32]: ('user_a', 'address_a', 987)
```

To achieve this you can **subclass `dict` and overwrite only the `__getitem__` method**:

```
class c_dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = super(c_dict, self).__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(val, tuple):
            return tuple(
                '{0}_{1}'.format(el, key) 
                if isinstance(el, str) 
                else el 
                for el in val
                )
        else:
            return val
```

This custom dictionary, `c_dict`, will behave like a normal dictionary unless you get a value that of type `tuple` that holds elements of type `str` in which chase the key is added to the element but only upon returning them.

With this approach you do not store the key inside the values, it keeps the conceptual separation intact.

**You can easily switch between a normal `dict` and this custom `c_dict`**. So if you want to get rid of this special way to return values, simply do `users = dict(users)` and `users` is again a plain simple `dict`. This works either way:

```
In [41]: users = {'a': ('user', 'address', 12)}
In [42]: users['a']
Out[42]: ('user', 'address', 12)
In [43]: users = c_dict(users)
In [44]: users['a']
Out[44]: ('user_a', 'address_a', 12)
In [45]: users = dict(users)
In [46]: users['a']
Out[46]: ('user', 'address', 12)
```

*Hope that helped. Happy coding!*

Comment: the main reason I need to use that is to build a switch in python my code is more like var = {'a': lambda x: somesubclass('a', x), 'b': lambda x: anothersubclass('b', x), 'c':lambda x:thirdsubclass('c', x } then i can use as  somesubclass_instance = var['a']('xxxxxxx')